# httpresonse returns The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, httprequest

I have a C# script which sends the http request to the specified URL 
the response returned to this url is 'The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.'
But when I try to access this URL through a browser , the page loads successfully.
Why does this happen? Am i missing something in my code?

````
public void VerifyURL(string url)
        {
            Uri urlcheck = new Uri(url);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlcheck.AbsoluteUri);
            request.Timeout = 15000;

            HttpWebResponse response;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(HttpStatusCode.Found.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                //return false; //could not connect to the internet (maybe) 
            }
        }```
````

Comment: When you access the page through a browser, do you see a warning regarding the certificate?

Comment: Yes.  The c# library does not use the same default headers in the html that the webpage uses.  Best way of solving is to use a sniffer and capture the first request from the browser.  Then do same with c# first request.  Then compare the two requests.  Make the C# app look like the browser.